# Find all React components in js, jsx and tsx by reading file using nodejs fs.readSync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vscode-extensions

I would love to know if there is a way i can find all react components in a given .js | .tsx file by using a program to read the content of the file.
I tried using regex i got from chatgpt but it seems not to work like so

```
 const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
 const componentRegex = /(?:class|function)\s+([A-Z]\w+)\s+extends\s+React.Component/g;
 let match;

 while ((match = componentRegex.exec(fileContent)) !== null) {
  components.push(match[1]);
 5}
```

... and i am not very good at using regex

Are there other efficient ways please help me

Comment: Regex isn't the most reliable (or efficient) solution for this,  Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) parsing would be the best solution for this. Babel (@babel/parser) should work in your case. Let me know if you have any trouble working with it!

Comment: Okay I'll definitely check it out and get back to you if there's a problem . Thank you so much